# Drupal 7 - Changing Layout of Article View

Tags: drupal, layout, view, slideshow, article

I tried Googling this, but it is so specific I didn't come across anything relevant. I currently have a view slideshow for article posts and it looks like this:
[image]

But I want it to look like this:
[image]

Basically I would just like two columns, for image and body, rather than two rows. I have attempted to change the image and body to "inline" in the View Fields settings, but this simply aligned the body text to the last line next to the image and the rest was still below the image.

I have a feeling I can accomplish this in CSS, but I can't figure out how to do it without having the image and text potentially overlap if the image is too large.

Any help on this matter and you will be helping me immensely! Thank you in advance!

UPDATE:
I understand basic CSS, this is not a post as to if to use CSS or not or what CSS is, it is specifically what attributes in CSS to use, I have tried setting each field to a unique CSS class and position:absolute and then right:0px/left:0px with the same issues described above, any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You are correct - this is pretty much CSS basics. You can get a fantastic reference at http://w3schools.com to answer your CSS and markup related queries.

I recommend using the views tool to add some unique classes to the fields so it's easy to style.

Comment: I agree, if this were a basic page the CSS would be easy, but this is specifically a View Slideshow for an Article and even when I do give the fields unique classes, the CSS doesn't stay consistent across the slides

Answer (score 0):

Using an [WYSIWYG](http://drupal.org/project/wysiwyg) editor you can do it quite easy. You can use with CKEditor for example. 
You can do it with plain html also, see this [example](http://www.echoecho.com/htmlimages08.htm) or just use CSS

Comment: I gave the fields unique CSS classes and tried to use position:absolute and right:0px/left:0px and I still get the same issue?

Comment: Also this is a View Slideshow of an Article, the Article page is fine just the view

Answer (score 0):

there is a nice article [here](http://www.acquia.com/blog/drupal-how-get-inline-images-your-drupal-site) about what you want to do.

another solution: you can use "open framework". it is a theme for drupal 7 and is based on bootstrap.
then you can use its classes.[like postcard layouts](https://openframework.stanford.edu/postcard-layouts)
i used that in my own site: [quicklearn.ir](http://quicklearn.ir/)
click on the last filed in field session in your views, then go to REWRITE RESULTS and wrap your fields with that class.something like this:

```
<div class="postcard-right-wrap">
<div>[field_image]</div>
<div><h3>[title]</h3></div>
<div>[body-summary]</div>
</div>
```

Comment: please include the essence required to answer the question and keep the link as source + more details.